# I use scaper script and retrofit it with info from a medical site but it doesn't seem to create the csv file I'm looking to create

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scraper

I have used this script I found for a scraper tool that gathers the names of all the dentists listed on the web page. When I run it, no new csv file is created with the aggregated data I'm looking for.Here's the script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests as rq
import csv

url = "https://www.healthgrades.com/usearch?what=Dentistry&where=Canal%20Street%2C%20NY%2010013&city=Canal%20Street&state=NY&pt=40.720901%2C%20-74.008904&zip=10013&neCorner=40.739420717131885%2C-73.98771539161403&swCorner=40.70233998462754%2C-74.03007248950355&mapCenter=40.720901%2C-74.008904&zoomLevel=14.6&mapChanged=false&pageNum=2"
GeT = rq.get(url)
soup = bs(GeT.content, "html.parser")

data_1 = soup.find_all ('div',{'class':'card-content__details'})

doctors_list = []

for item in data_1:
    try:
        first = item.contents[2].find_all('div',{'class':'details'})[1].text
    except:
        first = ''


    doctors_list.append(first)  

    with open('newfile.csv','w') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        for row in doctors_list:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Are you sure the `with` statement is supposed to be indented inside the `for` loop?

Comment: from the previous script that I've run for the original file , it seems so

Comment: What does `names = [first]` do?

Comment: it was meant to store scraped data but I just changed that and appended the first variable to the doctors_list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example JSON response: https://bpaste.net/show/fcb53d9bc16f

```
>>> import requests
... 
... BASE_URL = 'https://www.healthgrades.com/api3/usearch'
... 
... params = {
...     'userLocalTime':'22:37',
...     'what':'Dentistry',
...     'where':'Canal Street, NY 10013',
...     'pt':'40.720901, -74.008904',
...     'sort.provider':'bestmatch',
...     'category':'provider',
...     'sessionId':'Sb93293f932c6bc56',
...     'requestId':'Rac7ffe6e6256eba3',
...     'pageSize.provider':'20',
...     'pageNum':'2',
...     'isFirstRequest':'true',
...     'debug':'false',
...     'isAtlas':'true',
...     'action':'refresh',
...     'neCorner':'40.744526282819244,-73.99060337556104',
...     'swCorner':'40.69723118200452,-74.02724113269275'
... }
... r = requests.get(BASE_URL, params=params)
... r.raise_for_status()
>>> dentists = r.json()['search']['searchResults']['provider']['results']
>>> for dentist in dentists:
...     print(dentist['displayName'])
... 
Dr. Raphael Santore, DDS
Dr. Gain Lu, DDS
Dr. Molly Lim, DDS
Dr. Anne Yu, DDS
Dr. Charmaine Ip, DMD
Dr. Devi Konar, DDS
Dr. Christopher Perez, DMD
Dr. Lee Gold, DDS
Dr. Elaine Wong, DDS
Dr. Fan Mou, DDS
Dr. Henry Wong, DDS
Dr. Shauna Fung, DDS
Dr. Emilie Fong, DDS
Dr. Nancy Ma, DDS
Dr. Charles Tiu, DDS
Dr. Glenn Chiarello, DDS
Dr. John Nosti, DMD
Dr. Loi Chan, DDS
Dr. Charles Hashim, DDS
Dr. David Azar, DDS
Dr. Jenny Zhu, DDS
Dr. Stanton Young, DMD
Dr. Pankaj Singh, DDS
Dr. Lawrence Tam, DDS
Dr. Alina Lukashevsky, DDS
Dr. Maureen Khoo, DDS
Dr. Mailin Lai, DDS
Dr. Stewart Neidle, DDS
Danielle Danzi, DDM
Dr. Justin Cohen, DMD
Dr. Weihsin Men, DMD
Dr. Anthony Kail, DDS
Sima Epstein
Dr. Christian Bilius, DDS
Dr. Jeffrey Shapiro, DDS
Dr. Donald Ingerman, DDS

>>> featured_dentists = r.json()['featuredProviders']
>>> for dentist in featured_dentists:
...     print(dentist['displayName'])
... 
Dr. Ora Canter, DDS
Dr. Alfred Shirzadnia, DDS
Dr. Henry Nogid, DDS
```